# SPOJ wrong answer ADDREV

Tags: c++, debugging

My code is quite simple and straightforward. I get "wrong answer" on submission though. I have no clue why that happens! Here is the code...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

void sum(string num)
{
  int i,len=num.length();
  int j=len-1;
  int carry=0;
  string answer;
  int s=0;
  for(i=0,j;i<len;i++,j--)
  {
    s = (num[i]-'0')+(num[j]-'0')+carry;
if (s>10&&j!=0)
{ 
      carry = s/10;
  s = s%10; 
    } 
else if (s>10&&j==0)
{ 
      carry=s/10; s=s%10; answer+=s+'0';answer+=carry+'0'; break;
    }   
answer+=s+'0';
  }
  int sz=answer.size();for(int j=sz-1;j>=0;j--) cout<<answer[j];
  }

  int main(int argc,char **argv)
  {
    int n;cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
  string no;cin>>no;
  sum(no);cout<<endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Reformat your code, it's unreadable.

Comment: What is the failure message? (took to long, wrong answer, etc)

Comment: Some sort of hint of what the code is supposed to do would be nice as well.

Comment: Whatever this code is doing does not appear to be close to what the ADDREV challenge asks for (http://www.spoj.pl/problems/ADDREV/). To begin with, make sure that your code gives a correct answer for the sample input (even though sometimes the sample input doesn't cover corner cases, in which case you'll have to study the problem description more carefully).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't analysed your code, but here are few tips about SPOJ:

1. Re-read the description carefully, see if you haven't missed anything.
2. Check for edge cases, see if your output makes any sense.
3. Be careful about whitespace. Check your output for extraneous newlines/spaces at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int reverse(long long int n);
int main()
{
        int t;
        scanf("%d",&t);
        while(t--)
        {
                long long int m,n;
                scanf("%lld %lld",&m,&n);
                m = reverse(m) + reverse(n);
                n = reverse(m);
                printf("%lld\n",n);
        }
        return 0;
}
int reverse(long long int n)
{
        long long int i=0,y=0,x=n;
        while(x)
        {
                y++;
                x = x/10;
        }
        while(y)
        {
                i = i + (n%10)*pow(10,y-1);
                n = n/10;
                y--;
        }
        return i;
}
```

This code get accepted